# Proof that $f\big(f(x)\big)$ exists, where $f(x)=\frac{4x+3}{6x-4}$

Tags: functions

$$f(x)=\frac{4x+3}{6x-4}$$

$\operatorname {Dom}f= \Bbb{R}\setminus\left\{\frac23\right\}$

$\operatorname {Ran}f=\Bbb R$

Since $\operatorname {Ran} f$ is not a subset of $\operatorname {Dom} f$,
therefore, $f\circ f$ does not exist.

---

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Making appropriate domain restrictions, you have that $f\circ f=\mathrm{id}$.

Comment: Note that image of $f$ is not $\mathbb{R}$. There is no real $x$ such that $f(x)=\frac 2 3$. Not that I see what this has to do with finding $f(f(x))$.

Comment: @gandalf61 That depends on whether by range they mean "codomain" or "image".

Comment: @eyeballfrog I mean image when I say range

Comment: I am sorry, my bad.

Comment: *Is* the range of $f$ equal to $\mathbb R$ though?  Or more to the point is the naughty $\frac 23$ in the image of $f$?  Is there and $x$ where $f(x) = \frac 23$?

Comment: @fleablood Thank you! I have got my mistake, this question is wrong.

Comment: @Subhajit The range doesn't include {2/3} so the composite function exists

Comment: @user810213 The fact that the domain and image of $f$ happen to be the same has nothing to do with the existence of $f(f(x))$. See my extended answer below for more details.

Comment: Suppose we let $g(x)=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and ask about $f\circ g$. Would you say that it is undefined just because the range of $g$ is not a subset of the domain of $f$?

Comment: What does "existence" mean?  All functions exist if you restrict the domains tightly enough.  No one claims $f(x) = \frac {4x+3}{6x-4}$ does "not exist" because $f(\frac 23)$ is undefined (or should we?); we simply claim Dom $f$ does not include $\frac 23$.  So even if there was a $w\ne \frac 23$ where $f(w)=\frac 23$ then we would not claim $f\circ f$ does "not exist" (or would we?); we'd simply claim Dom $f\circ f$ does not include $\frac 23$ or $w$.  Hence gandalf's comments.

Comment: "Would you say that it is undefined just because the range of g is not a subset of the domain of f?"  I was presuming the OP would.  We would have to restrict the domain of $f\circ g$ from all of $\mathbb R$ to the pre-image of the Domain of $f$. So saying $f\circ g$ does "not exist" *on the entirety of the Domain of $g$* is a reasonable (but maybe ill-advised) thing to say.... But I don't think we should blanketly state that $f\circ g$ "does not exist".

Comment: @BarryCipra I would say that $f\circ  g$ is undefined for $x=\frac 23$

Comment: @user810213, but the range of $g$ is not a subset of the domain of $f$. So why does the analogous statement become a reason for concluding that $f\circ f$ doesn't exist at all? Wouldn't it make more sense to figure out the values for which $f(f(x))$ doesn't make sense and simply say that $f\circ f$ is undefined for those values?

Comment: @BarryCipra Sorry, I am a noob. One more thing, do mathematicians use the term, 'existence' of a function generally or they just say that, "Hey we can always restrict the domain and make the image real for those values"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the image of $f$ is not the whole of $\mathbb{R}$. There is no value of $x$ such that $f(x)=\frac 2 3$.

However, this does not prevent $f(f(x))$ existing for all values of $x$ apart from $x= \frac 2 3$. Indeed, for all other values of $x$ we have $f(f(x))=x$.

The fact that the domain and the image of $f$ happen to be the same in this case has nothing to do with the existence of $f(f(x))$. Consider

$g(x)=\frac 1 {x+1}$

The domain of $g$ is $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{ -1 \}$; the image of $g$ is $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$; and

$g(g(x)) = \frac {x+1}{x+2}$

with domain $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{-1,-2 \}$.

Comment: "The fact that the domain and the image of f happen to be the same in this case has nothing to do with the existence of f(f(x)). "  I took the question as the OP stated it, to mean that that the presumed domain of $f\circ f$ would be the domain of $f$.  And that as $g\circ g(-2)$ isnt defined that $g\circ g:\mathbb R\setminus\{-1\}\to \mathbb R$ does "not exist" as it is not defined for the same domain as $g$.... Of course these is semantics.  ( $h\circ h$ will always "exist" if we restrict the domain tightly enough... to the emptyset if need be....)

Answer (score 0):

> Where have I gone wrong?

You have assume that the range/image of $f$ is $\mathbb R$ but see no justification for that.

$f\circ f(x) = \frac {4\frac{4x + 3}{6x -4} + 3}{6\frac{4x + 3}{6x -4} -4}$ which assuming $6x-4 \ne 0$ and $6\frac{4x + 3}{6x -4} -4\ne 0$ is equal to

$\frac {4(4x + 3) + 3({6x -4})}{6(4x + 3) -4(6x -4)}=\frac {34x}{34}=x$.

Our restriction is that $6x-4 \ne 0$ or $x \ne \frac 23$; and that $6\frac{4x + 3}{6x -4} -4\ne 0$ or $6(4x+3) \ne 4(6x-4)$ or that $18\ne -16$ (which it doesn't).

So the domean of $f\circ f$ is the same as the domain of $f$, namely, $\mathbb R-\{\frac 23\}$

.....

Now you assume that the range/image of $f$ would include a value $y = f(w) = \frac 23$ and the $f(y) = f(f(w)) = f(\frac 23)$ would throw a monkey wrench into the equation.

Apparently, that didnt happen.

Why didn't it?

Well $f(w) = \frac {4w +3}{6w -4} =\frac 23$ would mean $3(4w+3) = 2(6w-4)\implies 9=-8$.  So $\frac 23$ is not in the range/image of $f$.

.......

It's important to note that we write $f: A\to B$ then that does not mean $f$ is surjective and that although $B$ is the codomain, that does not mean that $B$ is the image.  (They've changed the definitions since I was in high school; I no longer know what the definition of "range" is.)

We could ask what *is* the image of $f$ but.... so long as $\frac 23$ is not in the image we are good.

.......

If $y \in Im(f)$ then there is an $x$ so that $y = \frac {4x+3}{6x-4}$ so $y(6x-4)=4x+3$.

$x(6y-4)=3+4y$ so $x = \frac{3+4y}{6y-4}$ which has a solution for all $y$ *except* $y=\frac 23$.

So the image of $f$ is $\mathbb R-\{\frac 23\}$.

ANd $f:\mathbb R-\{\frac 23\}\to \mathbb R-\{\frac 23\}$ is a bijection.

Cool.